# What is the problem in finding domain of $ \frac{x-3}{(x+3)(\sqrt{x^2-4})} $?

Tags: functions

I'm having

> $$ f(x)=\frac{x-3}{(x+3)(\sqrt{x^2-4})} $$

Now, if I want to find its **domain**,
I should write:

> $$ x+3 ≠ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{AND} \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \  (x+2)(x-2) >0
>  $$

$ \text{as the denominator must be non-vanishing} \\ $

- So I get

> $ (-∞,-3) \cup (-3,-2) \cup (2,∞) $

**Which is of course correct**

**But.**

If I use

> $ (x+2)>0 $ AND $ (x-2)>0 $

**separately**, I **don't** get $ (-∞,-3) \cup (-3,-2) $ .

**Why?** Can't I do it **separately?**

Comment: Because if both $(x-2)$ and $(x+2)$ are negative, their product also will be positive.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Oh yes! That's exactly the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, in the denominator :

$x \not = -3$ and the expression under the root must be positive, i.e.

$(x-2)(x+2)>0.$

1) The product is positive if both factors are positive:

$x-2 >0$ and $x+2 >0,$

$x>2$ and $x>-2$, hence $x>2.$

2) The product is positive if both factors are negative:

$x-2<0$ and $x+2<0$,

$x<2$ and $x<-2$, hence $x < -2.$

Comment: After final "hence" do you want $x<-2$? [typo?]

Comment: coffeemath.Thanks! Peter

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$x^2-4>0 \iff (x-2)(x+2)>0 \iff \begin{cases}x-2>0 \land x+2>0\\\\x-2<0 \land x+2<0 \end{cases}$$